# Use Globiflow to pull certain information from an email

Tags: php, email, citrix, podio

I am trying to use Globiflow to identify information from an email reply. I am using the "Email to app" feature in Podio where an individual could email that particular email and have the information go straight to the app. Here are the fields within the app:

- Email - (Mapped for Sender)(Also includes their name sometimes)
- Client
- Job Title - (Mapped for Email Subject)
- Description of Job - (Mapped for Email Body)
- Would Like Done By - (Date box)
- Urgency - (Field selection of either Routine, Priority, or Urgent)
- Date Submitted
- Status

Within the email I am trying to make it where the client can identify themselves (by account email), when they would like the project done by, and the urgency of it. They do this with the following key words:

- Account Email: - (Followed by the email they have on their account)
- Date: - (Followed by date time format in m/d/y)
- Urgency: - (Followed by text of either Routine, Priority, or Urgent)

I need the system to identify these keywords and map them to the appropriate fields within the app.

Currently I have no problem with the Urgency: keyword and mapping it to the app field. I am doing this with `preg_match_gf("/Urgency:\s([a-z-\s]+^)/ism", strip_tags_gf([(Project) Description of Job]),1)` and it is working just fine.

For the other two however, I am not finding the same fortune. I have tried many different patterns with the coding to try and identify the Date: and Account Email: keywords by have been unsuccessful.

I have even tried stristr with the date `stristr([(Project) Description of Job],"Date:")` and then try to strip it in another custom variable with `preg_match_gf("/Date:\s([0-9\(\)\-\s]+^)/ism", [(Variable) date], strip_tags_gf([(Variable) date]),1)` but I am still not successful. Of course I have also tried these with just and preg_match and strip_tag as well.

I would preferably like to pull the email straight from the email recipient field, but sometimes this will also include the senders name like this: Zach Alexander . Because it does this I am having a difficult time pulling just the email from the sender profile. That is why I am having them identify it with the keyword Account Email: in the email body.

In short, I need this system to identify the clients email, if they added keywords and then property map those keyword entries to the Podio fields.

I added some screen shots to show where I am currently at.

Globiflow Image

[image]

Podio Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I am posting late, but maybe it will help others

Use these  patterns

**for Date:**

```
preg_match_gf("/Date:\s(.*)/i", strip_tags_gf([(Call) Notes]), 1)
```

**for Account Email**

```
preg_match_gf("/Account Email:\s(.*)/i", strip_tags_gf([(Call) Notes]), 1)
```

or

```
preg_match_gf("/Email:\s(.*)/i", strip_tags_gf([(Call) Notes]), 1)
```

Thank You!